# Showing newest values in subdocument when finding a document

Tags: mongodb

Given the following document structure:

```
{
  _id: "abc123",
  name: "Some name",
  properties: [
    {
      definition: "temp",
      values: [
        {
          created: 1376061128,
          value: 82
        },
        {
          created: 1376062368,
          value: 85
        },
        {
          created: 1376062627,
          value: 88
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      definition: "alert",
      values: [
        {
          created: 1376061128,
          value: 0
        },
        {
          created: 1376062368,
          value: 1
        },
        {
          created: 1376062627,
          value: 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to be able to return a document with only the "newest" (based on created) values for each property like so:

```
{
  _id: "abc123",
  name: "Some name",
  properties: [
    {
      definition: "temp",
      values: [
        created: 1376062627,
        value: 88
      ]
    },
    {
      definition: "alert",
      values: [
        created: 1376062627,
        value: 0
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm fairly new at dealing with MongoDB and map/reduce in general so I'm not sure what direction I should be looking at. This is a new data model so if there are suggestions as to modifications to the document model I'd be willing to listen as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the values are just pushed to the array in a timely order (as your data suggests), you can use: `db.coll.find({}, {"properties.values" : {$slice : -1}})`

It doesn't guarantee newest. It will return the last item in array. Since your values array is implicitly sorted by created this will work.

Since aggregation framework doesn't let you unwind nested arrays, if this is not the case (values are not being pushed by created), you will have to use map reduce I think.

Comment: In this case the values are always time-based so this is perfect. I was overcomplicating it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In aggregation pipeline you can use [`$first`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/first/) and [`$last`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/last/) operators, which can be helpful for your case. It took me a while to construct an aggregate pipe for this, it may be not optimal, but it is working:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$unwind : "$properties"},
    {$unwind : "$properties.values"},
    {$sort : {
        "_id" : 1,
        "name" : 1,
        "properties.definition" : 1,
        "properties.values.created" : 1
    }},
    {$group : {
        "_id" : {
            "_id" : "$_id",
            "name" : "$name",
            "definition" : "$properties.definition"
        },
        "created" : {$last : "$properties.values.created"},
        "value" : {$last : "$properties.values.value"}
    }}
])
```

And the result is:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : {
                "_id" : "abc123",
                "name" : "Some name",
                "definition" : "temp"
            },
            "created" : 1376062627,
            "value" : 88
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "_id" : "abc123",
                "name" : "Some name",
                "definition" : "alert"
            },
            "created" : 1376062627,
            "value" : 0
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

You may need a bit transformation of the result, but [it is not a problem](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/project/), right?

Comment: this may work, but the query will be slow and it seems too much for such a simple requirement.

Comment: I'm not saying it is perfect or so. If OP is 100% sure that properties are ordered by time, then `$slice` may work as per @orid.

Comment: This is more generic, so +1